# delayed_job doesn't work (rails 3.1.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Trying to use gem delayed_job from collectiveidea(https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) in my project, but it throws exception: "uninitialized constant Delayed::DelayProxy::Job".

What I've done to install it:
Gemfile:

```
gem 'daemons'
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

Command line:

```
bundle install
rails generate delayed_job:active_record
rake db:migrate
rake jobs:work
```

Using it in controller:

```
Video.delay.convert
```

I've done all of this like in instruction, but it doesn't work. Googled much, but can't find helpful instruction. I've found railscasts sources with delay_work, but all code(Gemfile, script, controllers, models) is the same as mine, but RC's code works, mine - no.

P.S.: I'm new to ruby and rails, may be my question is lame, but I'm trying to solve this problem second day. And... sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: I've just tried to use v. 2.1.4, but it doesn't work too. And in the railscasts sources last version is used and works well.

Comment: I've just solved my problem. Sorry if I wasted anybody's time.

All I needed to do is to write to initializer(initializers/delayed_job_config.rb):

    Delayed::Worker.backend = :active_record
And **restart the web-server**. It doesn't apply without restart even in develop environment.

Comment: You might consider answering your own question with the info in the comment above. It will help others when searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment above:

> All I needed to do is to write to
>   initializer(initializers/delayed_job_config.rb):
>   Delayed::Worker.backend = :active_record And **restart the web-server.**
>   It doesn't apply without restart even in develop environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', :git => 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record.git'
```